# Convert document structure in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I have thousands of documents like this:

```
{
    country:"ES",
    month: 4,
    cars: [
     {
           name: "audi a5",
           doors: 1,
           PRICE: 40
     },
     {
           name: "audi a6",
           doors: 3,
           PRICE: 100
     },
   ]
}
```

What is the best way to convert it them to another form:

```
[
  {
  name:"audi a5",
         doors: 1,
         prices:[
           {month:4,country:"ES",price:40},
           {month:5,country:"ES",price:44},
           ....
           ]
  },
  {
  name:"audi a6",
       doors: 3,
       prices:[
         {month:4,country:"ES",price:100},
         {month:5,country:"ES",price:120},
         ....
       ]
  },
]
```

I tried list function but without success. May be too many elements it tries to compile.
Each original doc contains about 20 cars.
There are about 200 cars at all. 100 countries and 12 months.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to change them permanently, checkout `costco`: http://harthur.github.io/costco/

Depending on how many documents you are changing it may be rather slow--as all the documents to be changed are loaded into the browser, transformed, and *then* sent back to the Apache CouchDB or Cloudant.

Hope that helps, Ilya.

Comment: costco is interesting but in my case map function is not enough.
Prices for cars are spread over many documents. So either reduce or list function required if I understand it properly.

Comment: True. Looks like your turning a single document into several. If you can get the result out as a `_list`, you could use that output to create new documents--removing the original doc once it's parts have become new docs (checkout _bulk_docs). If you're on Cloudant, Chained MapReduce might also do the trick: http://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html